# How does custom model binding work for a property of an unknown type at compile time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have a UI designer on the front end which creates a layout.

A layout has rows, and each row has columns, and each column has widgets. The widgets are identified by a key and they also have a config.

```
public class Layout
{
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<Row>? Rows { get; init; }
}

public record Row
{
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<Column>? Columns { get; init; }
}

public record Column
{
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<Widget>? Widgets { get; init; }
}

public record Widget
{
    [Required]
    public string? WidgetTypeKey { get; init; }

    public object? Config { get; init; }
}
```

The config of a widget could be any number of C# classes that don't share anything in common. I don't know which one it will be until I determine the widget type by key. So therefore I have used `object` as the type.

But the config classes still have validation requirements such as `[Required]`, `[Range]`, `[MaxLength]` and so on.

I can resolve the config class at run time, but I'm not sure how to go about this so that I still get all of the usual ASP.NET validation through the pipeline.

At first I thought I could attach `[BindModel]` to the Config property or the Widget class and use my own `IModelBinder`, but these aren't used at all. ASP.NET only considers them if they're at the top of the hierarchy. I.e. the layout. So the model binder is never hit.

I also tried writing an `IModelBinderProvider`, but again the same problem. The provider is only hit for the initial Layout type, but nothing beyond that. It never queries again for any other type.

I also experimented with generics, thinking that maybe Config could be a `TConfig` type, but I have no idea how to resolve that at runtime during model binding. Especially since each widget can be a different type.

I guess I could write my own model binder for a layout, but then I miss out on all the automated validation don't I?

Is this too crazy to attempt? Has anyone ever successfully resolved a dynamic object at runtime with a deeply-nested complex type while also letting ASP.NET core do its full validation pipeline?

Comment: I believe that the problem is `any number of C# classes that don't share anything in common` which is not necessary.

Comment: You can unify all the configurations into one class and make sub config classes null if they are not being set for the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Layout` class should implement [IValidatableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject) interface with [Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator) class:

```
public class Layout : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ...
        Validator.TryValidate(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

You should have the validation logic with `System.ComponentModel` namespace, ASP.NET Core will pick it up automatically.